# port knocking using iptables

Tags: iptables

I am using following iptables rules for port knocking. Everything works well, but I would like to improve it by being able to knock from HOST_1 and thereby opening the SSH port for HOST_2. Could somebody please advise if/how that could be done? One possibility is to fake the source IP while port knocking (hping3 -p 100 -a $HOST_2 11.22.33.44). That works, but I would prefer to implement this using iptables.

```
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m recent --rcheck --seconds 5 --name KNOCK3 --rsource -j STATE3
-A INPUT -m recent --rcheck --seconds 5 --name KNOCK2 --rsource -j STATE2
-A INPUT -m recent --rcheck --seconds 5 --name KNOCK1 --rsource -j STATE1

-A INPUT -j STATE0

-A STATE0 -m recent --remove --name KNOCK1,KNOCK2,KNOCK3 --rsource
-A STATE0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 100 -m recent --set --name KNOCK1 --rsource -j DROP
-A STATE0 -j DROP

-A STATE1 -m recent --remove --name KNOCK1,KNOCK2,KNOCK3 --rsource
-A STATE1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 200 -m recent --set --name KNOCK2 --rsource -j DROP
-A STATE1 -j DROP

-A STATE2 -m recent --remove --name KNOCK1,KNOCK2,KNOCK3 --rsource
-A STATE2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 300 -m recent --set --name KNOCK3 --rsource -j DROP
-A STATE2 -j DROP

-A STATE3 -m recent --remove --name KNOCK1,KNOCK2,KNOCK3 --rsource
-A STATE3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A STATE3 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two hosts are fixed IP addresses, you should just need to add the source IP option (-s) for the appropriate rules above where the knock names are set.  Eg. replace the HOST_1 and HOST_2 values below with valid IPs:

```
-A STATE0 -s HOST_1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 100 -m recent --set --name KNOCK1 --rsource -j DROP

-A STATE1 -s HOST_1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 200 -m recent --set --name KNOCK2 --rsource -j DROP

-A STATE2 -s HOST_1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 300 -m recent --set --name KNOCK3 --rsource -j DROP

-A STATE3 -s HOST_2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If your IPs are dynamic (eg. knocking from any given IP opens access to the next higher), I don't know of a way using just iptables.